# How to create startup tasks (or install dependencies) in Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, service, web-applications, deployment, cloud

There is a Cloud Service in Azure classic deployment model. In the Cloud Service you can add web role and set up a startup tasks. If your application has any dependencies that require installation on the destination VM or controll over IIS-related  settings, you can use a startup tasks to provide an unattended deployment for this configuration. For example, if you need installed software on the backend side, you can run MSI in startup task to install it.

Unfortunately, I can't find this functionality in new Azure Resource Manager model. My Web App need some installed software on backend side, but I can't figure out how to install it. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Web App (or App Service) doesn't give you control over the underlying OS. You should consider containerizing your app and run it through using e. g. ACI or AKS.

Answer (score 1):

A Cloud Service was nothing more than a VM with extended support in Visual Studio. Cloud Services are deprecated but you can still create a VM in Azure and install your dependencies.